# TypeError: $.get is not a function in node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

```
var $ = require("./jquery"); /*my jquery file (downloaded)*/
$.get("http://google.com",{},
    function(data) {});
```

> I am trying to run this code in cmd using the commande node but I got this problem:
> TypeError: $.get is not a function

**can anyone here help me !**

Comment: jQuery is a client-side library. Node is a JS server environment. (It won't have a `document` element for example). You may want [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) but without understanding what you're trying to do it's difficult to tell.

Comment: also, if you are simply trying to make an http request you should use a library like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)